# Is "I know where you are coming from" the equivalent in English of "Sé a dónde querés llegar" from Spanish?

Tags: translation

Lately, I hear a lot in English the phrase  "I know where you are coming from" . The funny/weird thing to me, it's that it seems to be used in the same situations we Spanish speaking people uses the phrase "Sé a dónde querés llegar" or "Sé a dónde quieres llegar" which translates to "I know where you are going to" . Are these equivalent phrases between English and Spanish? Or I just happened to find english speaking people who is talking incorrectly?

Comment: Do you mean literally "I know where you are going to" as in "I know you are going to San Francisco."? Because in English "I know where you are coming from" has an idiomatic meaning like "I can understand what you are thinking." See [*I know where you are coming from*](https://www.google.com/search?q=I+know+where+you+are+coming+from)

Comment: What's the context? What is the situation in which these people say "I know where you are coming from"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I know where you are coming from" means that the speaker understand the perspective and the motivation of the other person, even though it may not be obvious.

I'm not a native speaker of Spanish, but from my understanding of the Spanish phrase, I thought it is more similar to the English phrase "I know where you are going with this". While there are similarities, the two phrases are not exactly equivalent. The latter one emphasizes on the other person's intent or conclusion before it has been explicitly stated.